# Firefox doesn't set width correctly for SVG's parent div

Tags: css, svg, firefox, flexbox

I have an SVG without fixed width and height, it has only viewbox defined. I have one flex container which contains some child divs and inside those childs are the SVG's. With Chrome this works fine and SVG's are set side by side next to each other. But with Firefox those child divs have width 0px and all the SVG's are put on top of each other. How could I make those divs / svgs behave in Firefox same way as Chrome?

I tried the solution where I set the width of the divs in javascript, but I would prefer CSS only solution.

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
}

.first {
  background: green;
}

.second {
  background: yellow;
}

svg {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

Comment: Please don't link to an external site. Add a [minimal-reproducible-example StackOverflow Snippet](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). It will help readers execute your code with one click. And help create answers with one click.

Comment: There is a HTML and CSS example right there in the question @Danny'365CSI'Engelman. Can you expand on what you mean?

Comment: There was no code in question, just a codepen link

Comment: @Danny'365CSI'Engelman there was actually both. I have now removed the codepen link. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also have to add `width: auto` and `height: 100%` to the parent divs:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
}

.first {
  background: green;
}

.second {
  background: yellow;
}

svg, .first, .second {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    </svg>
  </div>
  <div class="second">
    <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100">
      <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
    </svg>
  </div>
</div>
```

Alternatively you can put the SVGs directly in the main container

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  height: 50px;
}

.first {
  background: green;
}

.second {
  background: yellow;
}

svg {
  width: auto;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="first">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
  </svg>
  <svg viewBox="0 0 100 100" class="second">
    <circle cx="50" cy="50" r="50" />
  </svg>
</div>
```